# Sap Odata Problem, Data Provider class does not exist

Tags: rest, odata, abap, sap-gateway

i have a porblem with a odata service.
The odata is already created by a former coworker. After a database update it still began not working.
It is active but if I open the gateway client there pop up only a error windows.

HTTP Receive failed: ICM_HTTP_CONNECTION_FAILED
Message no. /IWFND/COS_SUTIL100

So I have look into /iwfnd/error_log
/iwbep/error_log

And didnt see any log. The logs are empty.
So i have only the error message above when execute the odata in gateway client. Any suggestions are welcome

Second question.
If I test the same odata with https request it works!
There I am a little closer to the solution. In gw client there is the button for http and https. Connection to HTTP doesnt work.
But The connection to https works. I can select and test with different URI options. Though when I click at the EntitySet button, I get the following error:
Data Provider Implementation " " "  does not exist
And if I then look into the error logs there I can read:
Data Provider Implemenatation "z_xx_yy_MDL_002_BE" doesnt exist

Do you know this message for https what does it mean? Can someone help here?

Update 1:
Now I have another issue. In gw client I get status code 400 with error ' invalid filter. Provide filter for property.....'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description HTTP isn't configured for your system. You can check in transaction SMICM, from the menu choose Goto then Services. If HTTP isn't present then it's not configured. The Gateway Client has some ugly error messages unfortunately. Usually when I see something like this I immediately think that the connection is wrong, so 1.) ICM issue, 2.) The URL (especially the host, the port and ICF namespace (sap/opu/odata)) is formatted improperly.

About the second issue from your update, you can try these notes maybe: 2489991, 2645761